# MySql Query runs too slow after adding order by

Tags: mysql, performance, sorting

I'have an issue with a MySql Query

Two tables.
Persons tabel (25000 records)
persid (Primary key)
voornaam
tussenvoegsel
achternaam (index)

Line Ups tabel (370000 records)
Opstelkey (Primary key)
wid
Persid
volgorde
gesp
gesc

```
SELECT sum(o.gesc) as totgescoord,p.achternaam 
FROM opstelere1 o,personen1 p
where o.persid=p.persid
group by o.persid
```

Result above Query 6809 totaal, Query duration 0,0176 seconds

Adding Order By, the Query runs a lot slower.

```
SELECT sum(o.gesc) as totgescoord,p.achternaam 
FROM opstelere1 o,personen1 p
where o.persid=p.persid
group by o.persid
order by totgescoord desc
```

Result this Query 6809 totaal, Query duratiob 2,7740 seconds

Query only on Line Ups Table with use of persid

```
SELECT o.persid,sum(o.gesc) as totgescoord 
FROM opstelere1 o
group by o.persid
order by totgescoord desc
```

Resultaat Query 6809 totaal, Query duration 0,1732 seconds
But it's nice to see a name instead of a persid ;-)

Comment: Don´t use implicit joins and use explicit ones. Change (in the second query) the from as **FROM opstelere1 o join personen1 p on o.persid=p.persid**

Comment: And always GROUP BY all non-aggregated columns in the SELECT

Comment: @nacho I'v tried this 
SELECT sum(o.gesc) as totgescoord,p.achternaam 
FROM opstelere1 o
join personen1 p on o.persid=p.persid 
group by o.persid
order by totgescoord desc

unfortunately no difference

Comment: @Strawberry Sorry, but i don't know what you mean with "all non-aggregated columns" in this specific example

Comment: p.achternaam is an example of a non-aggregated column

Answer (score 0):

Turn the query inside-out.  This way it can *start* with the `GROUP BY`.  This lets it shrink 370000 rows into 6809 *before* touching the other table.  Then there are only 6809 lookups in that other table, not 370000.

```
SELECT  o2.totgescoord,
        p.achternaam 
    FROM ( SELECT persid, SUM(gesc) AS totgescoord
               FROM opstelere1
               GROUP BY persid ) AS o2
    JOIN personen1 AS p  ON p.persid = o2.persid
    ORDER BY o2,totgescoord DESC;
```

Also, `opstelere1` needs `INDEX(persid, gesc)` (in this order).

Your query is and example of explode-implode.

Comment: Thank you so much! This works perfect.
I've added an index as suggested.
Query duration 0,0667 seconds